# Reverse Proxy to login page

Tags: mod-rewrite, proxypass

I’m struggling to get my reverse proxy to work as desired… My Apache instance should work as a reverse proxy to a backend application server, like specified in the proxypass/proxyreverse directives below. 
Desired behaviour is: client requests `https://my_website/context_path`. This request should be redirected to `http://my_backend/context_path/loginServlet`
All other requests should be reverse proxied to the backend server.

```
   RewriteEngine  on

    RewriteCond  "%{REQUEST_URI}"  "https://my_website/context_path"
    RewriteRule ^/my_website$   http://my_backend/context_path/loginServlet$1

    ProxyPass /my_website/ http://my_backend/context_path/
    ProxyPassReverse /my_website/  http://my_backend/context_path/
```

Any help appreciated.
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Umm.. Are you sure you want to redirect all logins to a plain HTTP page served directly by your back-end? Is your back-end server even reachable from outside? If really so, it is possible:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName my_website.example.com
  ...

  RedirectMatch "^/context_path$" "http://my_backend.example.com/context_path/loginServlet"

  ProxyPass /context_path/ http://my_backend.example.com/context_path/
  ProxyPassReverse /context_path/  http://my_backend.example.com/context_path/
</VirtualHost>
```

But I think you are actually trying to achieve this; redirection to your proxy instead of the backend:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName my_website.example.com
  ...

  RedirectMatch "^/context_path$" "/context_path/loginServlet"

  ProxyPass /context_path/ http://my_backend.example.com/context_path/
  ProxyPassReverse /context_path/  http://my_backend.example.com/context_path/
</VirtualHost>
```

Notice that I used [`RedirectMatch`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) from mod_alias instead of `RewriteRule` from mod_proxy, because it is sufficient for such a simple external redirect and might be also easier to understand.

Comment: What I am trying to do is exactly described in your first example: this because the resource `loginServlet` is not an HTTP page but a Java servlet instead, which will detect particular HTTP headers used as "authentication tokens" and provide the user some functions based on his role. Those tokens are nothing but HTTP headers, added after the user logon on a commercial SSO product (CA SSO), which intercepts HTTP requests on my reverse proxy and prompots credentials before letting the Apache instance serve anything. hope the scenario is clear. Thank you for your interest! I'll let you know...

Comment: I'm glad I added examples for both, then. :)